# R: Remove (rm) a variable where that variable's name is a string stored in another variable

Tags: r

In R, I would like to be able to *remove* (*rm*) a variable, where that variable's name is stored in as a string in another variable.  Here's an example...

```
myVarName <- "toBeRemoved"
assign(myVarName, 3)
# mysteryremove is the function/command I'm looking for
mysteryremove(myVarName)
```

As you can see, I've put the value 3 in the variable named "toBeRemoved" using the *assign* command.  I'm looking for an analogous function to *assign* that will *remove*/*rm* the variable by variable name.

Note that I suppose I could just do this:

```
idx <- which(myVarName == ls())
if(length(idx)) rm(list = ls()[idx])
```

... but I was hoping for a simpler way.

Final note -- of course, if I knew what variable I was removing, I could simply do:

```
rm(toBeRemoved)
```

... but the problem is that I will not know the variable to be removed until the code is executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use

```
rm(list=myVarName)
```

The `list=` parameter takes character names. Though in general, i would caution against using `assign()` at all. It's often not necessary and just really messy. R is much happier with named lists in most cases.